# js работа с высотой дивов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вообщем суть такая, есть два дива, левый и правый, и надо сделать так что бы левый див брал высоту с правого, они с разными класами
.leftside
.rightside

[image: Не правльно]

[image: Правильно]

Заранее огромное Спасибо!
Вариант предлагать на подобных сайтах http://jsfiddle.net/

P.S: Желаемый вариант это - просто два дива и скрипт js который берет высоту с дива с классом .rightside и устанавливает ее на див .leftside :)
P.S.S: Два дива не оборачивать в один див!

Comment: покажите что вы сделали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/40ffjp4d/. Можно еще сверстать блоками как таблицу. То как вы ходите можно сделать только через js - оно вам надо http://jsfiddle.net/40ffjp4d/1/

```
$('#leftside').height($('#rightside').height());
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код прямо в ответ. Все посты должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки на jsfiddle могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! помогло ), вопрос можно считать закрытым)